# JIT/Hotspot technique book

Tags: java, jvm, virtualization, jit

Does anyone know of any good books or length web articles (or research articles??) that talk about the JIT techniques or hotspot techniques that are in-use by various JVM's or other virtual machine environments (python/ruby...)

Seems like it would be a very interesting read imho (although something with details is hard to find out there on the interwebs...)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at "[Oracle JRockit: The Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847198066)":

> Filled with careful step-by-step instructions and plenty of
>   screenshots, this tutorial shows you JRockit and how to get the most
>   from it. **All key concepts in the JRockit JVM, such as code generation,
>   memory management and other internals are introduced**. Performance
>   aspects of Java are discussed in detail. A complete guide to use the
>   tools in the JRockit Mission Control suite is also included, and much
>   more. This book is for intermediate to advanced Java Developers, who
>   want to monitor, diagnose, profile and enhance the performance of
>   their Java applications. **It is also for people who want to understand
>   more about the internal workings of a modern Java Virtual Machine or
>   adaptive runtime**. Parts of the book are suitable as course material
>   for education about runtimes.

Although it is about JRockit, you will find here also some comparison in JRockit and HotSpot implementation, some general approaches used by JVMs etc. This book is definitely worth to read..

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://java.sun.com/products/hotspot/whitepaper.html) whitepaper can be a good start, and then there are links at the end with additional resources.

Comment: Anything with up to date info?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Unfortunately most of the innovations in the Java land seem to be historic now :(